# Why is VGG-16 performing poor on CIFAR-10 dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I am trying to implement VGG-16 Convolutional Neural Network for the CIFAR-10 dataset with Tensorflow. But I am getting near about 10% of training accuracy. What is wrong with my code?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape

X_train = X_train/255
X_test = X_test/255
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", input_shape= 
(32,32,3),padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", 
padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", 
padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", 
padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", 
padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", 
padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", 
padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", 
padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", 
padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", 
padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", 
padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", 
padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", 
padding="same"),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation="relu"),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation="relu"),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])

model.summary()

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
          optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
          metrics=["accuracy"])

X_train[0].shape, y_train[0].shape

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100)
```

Comment: Did you notice that your loss does not decrease?

Comment: Yes....But, I could not find out why....

Comment: Use plain SGD with a tuned learning rate until the loss decreases, Adam does not work always and VGG is an edge case where it usually fails.

Comment: I tried.... But nothing imrove....Do you think there is any problem in the code??

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't found the right training schedule yet.

If you don't mind changing the model a bit, I recommend using Batchnorm after each convolution layer. In general, a model is easier to train with Batchnorm.

Furthermore, did you decrease the learning rate after a certain amount of iterations? At some point, a too-large learning rate may not decrease your training error anymore. The [ResNet](https://github.com/akamaster/pytorch_resnet_cifar10), for example, is trained with an initial learning rate of 0.1 for 100 epochs then with 0.01 for another 50 epochs and 0.001 for another 50 epochs.

Answer (score 0):

1. `y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)`
2. Change your loss to `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy`
3. lower your Adam learning rate to 0.001

then your code will work.